# Rails Geocoder says "can't convert string to integer"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongoid, rails-geocoder

Im my index index controller I have
   @usergeo = Geocoder.search("83.215.14.101")

result is:

```
Geocoder::Result::Freegeoip:0x007ff3ced35eb8 @data={
"city"=>"Salzburg", 
"region_code"=>"05", 
"region_name"=>"Salzburg", 
"metrocode"=>"", 
"zipcode"=>"",
"longitude"=>"13.0333", 
"latitude"=>"47.8", 
"country_code"=>"AT", 
"ip"=>"83.215.14.101", 
"country_name"=>"Austria"},

 @cache_hit=nil>]
```

.class means it is an array!

In the view I try this one:

```
<%= @usergeo["city"] %>
```

and the result is

```
can't convert String into Integer
```

Also an @usergeo[:city] does not work

any comment will be very helpful to me
thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `@usergeo.first.city` or `@usergeo[0].city` as you want to reference the @data sample in this case.

The reason you're getting that error is because you're basically trying to call Array["city"] on the result, but an array obviously expects an integer, not a string. This way you reference the object, which is a hash, and call ["city"] on that instead.

Answer (score 1):

Its no array its a `Geocoder::Result::Freegeoip` try `@usergeo.city` instead of `@usergeo["city"]`

Documentation of this class:

http://rubydoc.info/github/alexreisner/geocoder/master/Geocoder/Result/Freegeoip

Hope this helps you,...

Comment: When I try @usergeo.city I get: 

**undefined method `city' for #<Array:0x007ff3cdf21c50>**


:-(

Comment: please post output of `@usergeo.inspect`

Comment: exacly this: '[#<Geocoder::Result::Freegeoip:0x007ff2e0036008 @data={"city"=>"Salzburg", "region_code"=>"05", "region_name"=>"Salzburg", "metrocode"=>"", "zipcode"=>"", "longitude"=>"13.0333", "latitude"=>"47.8", "country_code"=>"AT", "ip"=>"83.215.14.101", "country_name"=>"Austria"}, @cache_hit=nil>]'

Comment: Then your post makes sense. You didnt copy all of it in the first way so I thought its not an array^^